# Velocity mails with header and footer

Tags: html, css, email, html-email, velocity

We have hundreds of copied mails all written in Velocity, but they are all based on the same design so I need an effective way to deal with headers and footers. Today every email is just copied from a template file and if I need to change something it's search and replace, and then pray that it'll catch it all.

I'm an absolute noob when it comes to Velocity, since I'm a designer so wanna know some expert ideas. But I have a few musts:

1) I must be able to preview the result while editing. Now I'm previewing in a browser, but it doesn't need to be in a browser. I just need to be able to see and make changes. Because of this I cannot just include a header and footer from other files since when I preview the mail the HTML and CSS isn't there. I must see what I'm designing in other words.

2) I want the header and footer to be the same everywhere. So I can change those and it ripples down to every mail. Then every email just handles the content.

Any pro-ideas?

Comment: Your question is quiet broad, the rules of StackOverflow ask an OP's to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so someone can help you out. To answer your question, you should be able to create templates that have certain parts identical for future use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no option to [view online](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/velocity-user/201711.mbox/browser) velocity templates, but you can use tool as [JMeter JSR 223](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) element to execute velocity templates on HTTP level.
- you will have to velocity core 2 jar which support JSR223.

You should create header.vel and footer.vel and add [include statement](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/user-guide.html#include) in your templates. For example:

```
 #include( "header.vel" )
 your template code....
 #include( "footer.vel" )
```

Comment: Ah, lovely, just what I was looking for. I'm not 100% on how we solved it in the background, but I use includes and then the developer created a page that renders the email (might have been with what you suggested) and sends it to my mail. So, I can work perfectly with it now and it's really smooth. Thanks!